# Установка модулей Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Пытаюсь установить модуль: https://github.com/hannesfrank/bstvis
После установки через pip в папке Lib/site-packages появилась папка 
bstvis-0.2.0.dist-info
Соответственно как я понимаю - это какая-то служебная информация, больше ничего нет, и импортировать модуль тоже не выходит. Никогда в таком виде с питоном не работал, подскажите, что делать чтобы модулем можно было пользоваться. Что и как нужно еще доставить?

Comment: как импортируем? Какая ошибка выходит?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import bstvis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bstvis'

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что установщик недоделан.

Решение: скачать папку bstvis и положить ее в Lib/site-packages.